# Parsing CSS by javascript. Inconsistency across Edge and Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, microsoft-edge

I am parsing with JS a CSS and I am trying to get the Unicode integer value of the "content" CSS rule but it's being handled differently across Edge and Chrome.

In Edge, the 'content' is a string of 7 chars:

[image]

In Chrome, it's a string of 3 chars:

[image]

`csDef` is my JS variable.

Here's how the CSS rule looks like:

[image]

Why is the value treated differently across the web-browses?
And in JS, and how can I get the Unicode integer value correctly across these web-browsers?

EDIT:

Here's how I load the CSS rules:

```
        var rulesForCssText = function (styleContent) {
            var doc = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument(""),
                styleElement = document.createElement("style");

            styleElement.textContent = styleContent;
            doc.body.appendChild(styleElement);

            return styleElement.sheet.cssRules;
        };

       var cssDefs =  Array.from(rulesForCssText(fileContent));
```

`fileContent` is the content of a file obtained by using a `File` object, I have an `input type="file"`and user selects the file from disk.

Comment: Maybe a silly question, but do you have uniform charset encoding across the page?

Comment: Good question. I have `@charset "utf-8";` set at the top of the CSS file. Let me add more info how I load the CSS rules

Comment: I think Edge doesn't support it. That might be the root of the problem. (btw, couldn't find it on CanIUse). However, I have found this: https://caniuse.com/#feat=textencoder. On MDN (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TextEncoder). Again, Edge is still the problem, but maybe the proposed polyfill (https://github.com/inexorabletash/text-encoding) can solve that?

Comment: Thanks. How exactly to use that polyfill? I see it takes a "buffer": `new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(uint8array);` How to get the `uint8array`? What should I put in it exactly?

Comment: To be honest, I have just stumbled upon that (that's why I didn't write an official answer). Just hoped that some additional info might help you, but I personally haven't used it so far.

Comment: Thanks. I am confused about how is it possible that the browser interpret it differently.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález Thanks for your reply. As you can see in the screenshot above, the Unicode char is the "content" value of a CSS file (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons/blob/master/docs/css/ionicons.min.css) So this isn't about "invalid" characters I think

Comment: You didn't answer my "what it's meant to be" question but I've realised it's an "add" icon thanks to your link. Sorry, it isn't invalid at all (I was wrong about that). I've composed a hopefully useful answer with my findings and deleted my incorrect comments to remove noise.

Comment: @DonBox Did you manage to get this sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

***Disclaimer***: I don't have a definitive answer but I've learnt a lot from the analysis and I think the results may be on interest for other people.

---

First of all, let me share two test cases. The CSS-based one reproduces the issue you describe:

```js
var d = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
var s = document.createElement("style");
s.textContent = '.foo{content: "\\20ac";}';
d.body.appendChild(s);
var c = s.sheet.cssRules[0].style.getPropertyValue("content");
console.log("String '%s' has length %d", c, c.length);
```

Desktop Firefox and Chrome render the numeric character reference (`String '"€"' has length 3`) and Edge doesn't (`String '"\20ac"' has length 7`).

Interestingly, a second HTML-based test case doesn't seem to exhibit any problem:

```js
var s = document.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].textContent;
console.log("String '%s' has length %d", s, s.length);
```

```html
<span>&#x20ac;</span>
```

Both browsers render the entity (`String '€' has length 1`).

So, who's right here? The [CSS Object Model (CSSOM) Editor’s Draft](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#dom-cssstyledeclaration-getpropertyvalue) says:

> If property is a case-sensitive match for a property name of a CSS
>   declaration in the declarations, then return the result of invoking
>   [serialize a CSS value](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom/#serialize-a-css-value) of that declaration.

… and here's where I got totally lost.

In any case, we're talking about complex web APIs that are still in active development and need to be implemented by different vendors. Whether it's a bug in one specific implementation or an overlook in the specs (less likely), it's an issue that your code needs to handle. A starting point could be:

```js
function browserRendersCharacterReferences() {
  var d = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
  var s = document.createElement("style");
  s.textContent = '.foo{content: "\\20ac";}';
  d.body.appendChild(s);
  return s.sheet.cssRules[0].style.getPropertyValue("content").length === 1;
}

function renderCharacterEntities(t) {
  // THIS FUNCTION IS WRONG, DON'T USE IT, IT'S JUST A QUICK EXAMPLE
  var r = /\\([\da-f]{4})\s?/gi;
  t = t.replace(r, function (match, codePoint) {
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(codePoint, 16));
  } );
  return t;
}

function rulesForCssText(css) {
  var d = document.implementation.createHTMLDocument("");
  var s = document.createElement("style");
  var c;
  s.textContent = css;
  d.body.appendChild(s);
  c = s.sheet.cssRules[0].style.getPropertyValue("content");
  if (!browserRendersCharacterReferences()) {
    c = renderCharacterEntities(c);
  }
  return c;
}

console.log(rulesForCssText('.foo{content: "\\20ac  and \\f102";}'));
```

---

P.S. I initially made some comments about `\f102` that were plain wrong. It's a completely valid [CSS character escape](https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-escapes):

> Escapes start with a backslash followed by the hexadecimal number that
>   represents the character's hexadecimal Unicode code point value.

… that maps to a totally valid Unicode character, albeit one in the [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas) block:

> a range of code points that, by definition, will not be assigned characters by the Unicode Consortium. […] They are intentionally left undefined so that third parties may define their own characters without conflicting with Unicode Consortium assignments.

In other words, it's reserved for private use. What kind of usages? For instance, the [Ionicons Font Icon](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionicons) that you appear to be using (a regular font that maps symbols to unused Unicode positions so it won't interfere with regular text):

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.2.2/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<i class="icon ion-ios-add"></i>
```